# Writing common Service Worker for complex System with multiple web Apps - Google Search

Tags: service-worker, google-search, workbox

While going through [Bringing service workers to Google Search](https://web.dev/google-search-sw), I came across `dispatch and routing framework` to handle sites with multiple web Apps. Snippet from the post:

> Google Search team built up a bespoke dispatch and routing framework
>   that could be configured to check for criteria like the query
>   parameters of the client page, and use those to determine which
>   specific code path to go down. Rather than hardcoding rules, the
>   system was built to be flexible and allow teams that share the URL
>   space, like Image Search and Shopping Search, to drop in their own
>   service worker logic down the line, if they decide to implement it.

I am dealing with a similar sort of complex problem with multiple web Apps and wanted to know the **bespoke dispatch and routing framework design** in detail.

1. Are we relying on `location.href` to know which App SW is dealing with and route the code path within SW accordingly?
2. Passing query parameters in url while registering SW would end up flip-flopping SW between App switches as the url would change, right?
3. Any challenges we dealt with the design?

Comment: I'm sorry, but because the code for the Google Search service worker isn't open source, it's difficult for me to describe their approach in greater detail.

Comment: Thanks @JeffPosnick! Appreciate your time here.